# How do I prevent libtorrent from creating a folder with a name?

Tags: c++, libtorrent

When downloading a torrent via libtorrent (a library for C ++), a folder with the name of the torrent is created, into which all the files are downloaded. In uTorrent, for example, you can remove the "Create subfolder" check mark when adding a torrent and everything will be fine. How to do it in libtorrent?

Is it possible to change the names of the torrent (folder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the directory from the file hierarchy, you can rename every file to the same name but with the torrent name root directory stripped off.

You should be able to do this both on the `torrent_info` before adding the torrent, or on the `torrent_handle` after adding it. But if you add it first the root directory will still be created.

See [rename_file()](http://libtorrent.org/reference-Core.html#rename_file())